# Can Drawmij's instant summons be dispelled without access to the sapphire?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

The spell [*Drawmij's instant summons*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/instant-summons) is cast on both a sapphire (the material component of the spell) and an object (the target of the spell) that is to be summoned by crushing the sapphire.

Normally, I would expect that casting [*dispel magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) on the target object would end the spell. However, the last line of the spell states:

> *Dispel magic* or a similar effect successfully applied to the sapphire
>   ends this spell's effect.

Is this adding an *additional* way to dispel the spell, or is it specifying the *only* way to dispel it? In other words, can I dispel the spell without accessing the sapphire, or do I *need* to target the sapphire in order to dispel the spell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, you can still use [*Dispel Magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) on the target object

[*Instant Summons*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/instant-summons) has a Range/Area parameter of "touch", and states:

> You touch an object weighing 10 pounds or less whose longest dimension is 6 feet or less. The spell leaves an invisible mark on its surface...

By any sensible interpretation of the rules, the object is the target of the spell, and is the subject of the permanent magical effect that the spell creates (until discharged by crushing the sapphire). *Dispel Magic* can dispel this spell effect upon the target object as usual - it's clearly a spell affecting the object, and there's no explicit restriction given that it can't.

*Instant Summons* is just unusual in that it **also** affects the material component used to cast it without immediately consuming it. The extra note in the spell's description essentially clarifies that the spell also affects the sapphire despite the fact that it is not strictly the target, and so *Dispel Magic* works on either end of the link created.